# node 6.9.1: How to render an integer status

Tags: node.js

In the node 0.12 i was rendering status like this:

```
res.send(10)
```

In 6.9.1 this is not allowed anymore, seems we can only render the status code in the HTTP status ranger. So i'm looking into how to fix this without changing the web client side.

jsonp seems to be my 1st choice

```
app.get("/test", function(req, res){
    res.jsonp({ "status": "10" });
});
```

but it there sth. like res.jsonp(10) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.send()` is still allowed as far as I can tell. It will send status 200 by default.

If you want to send a different status, you can either use `res.sendStatus()` (which will end the request), or `res.status()` followed by `res.send()`, for a custom response.

Comment: still getting this:     throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${statusCode}`);
    ^

RangeError: Invalid status code: 10
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:192:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/opt/ultra_app_0/iuvweb/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:157:8)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:571:10)

Comment: You are getting `RangeError: Invalid status code: 10` because, 10 is not valid status code I would say. Try to use some of valid status codes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set status like this:

```
res.status(200).json(json_response);
```

This will set the HTTP status code to 200 and json is optional you can use it if you need to send some JSON object.

This is part of Express API, and you can find some more information in their [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status). I assume that you are using Express 4.